# Can real-time deterministic multicounter automata recognize the marked palindrome language?

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, counter-automata

Consider the marked palindrome language which is defined as MPAL=$\{ w\#w^r | w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$.

It is easy to recognize MPAL using only a single stack.

My question is whether MPAL can be recognized by a real-time deterministic multicounter automaton.

Comment: You can easily use a Kolmogorov complexity argument to prove that a DMCA cannot correctly recognize MPAL.

Comment: Would it be possible to link to something about multi-counter and real-time automata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible and the reason looks simple (but I might overlook details).

After reading $w$ the number of reachable configurations of a real-time automaton is a polynomial in the lenght of $w$, whereas the number of different strings $w$ is exponential.

Answer (score 4):

I realized that in [Fischer, Meyer, and Rosenberg (1968)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01694011#page-1) Theorem 1.3, it is proven that "The language of marked palindrome is not recognizable by any one-way $k-CM$ which operates in time less than $T(n) = 2^{(n/2k)}$."

The same result also appears in [Petersen (2009)](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-02737-6_33).